# Delphi suddenly says that "[Warning Warning] Local file "Android\Debug\classes.dex" not found. Skipping deployment."

Tags: compiler-errors, firemonkey, delphi-2010

This is Delphi 10 Seattle on a LG Phone. 
I suddenly start getting the above error, after which my program will not load on my phone.This happens for nearly all programs. The programs are all compiled okay, but when I try to deploy them I get this error:

```
paclient command line
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\bin\paclient.exe -u8 --put="c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\bin\Artwork\Android\FM_LauncherIcon_96x96.png,.\Android\Debug\\CameraTest\res\drawable-xhdpi\,1,ic_launcher.png" 
paclient command line
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\17.0\bin\paclient.exe -u8 --put="C:\Program Files 
  (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\bin\Artwork\Android\FM_LauncherIcon_48x48.png,.\Android\Debug\\CameraTest\res\drawable-mdpi\,1,ic_launcher.png" 
[Warning Warning] Local file "Android\Debug\classes.dex" not found. Skipping deployment.
```

After which the deploy is aborted.

I can see there are two slashes in the name and I cannot find any reason for that. But that is also the case for the rare programs I can deploy, so apparently that is not the cause of the problem.

This works:

```
unit Unit8;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,

  System.IOUtils,
  FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo;


type
  TForm8 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form8: TForm8;

implementation
{$R *.fmx}
end.
```

This does not:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
  private
  public
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation
end.
```

The code that fails, started out as bigger program, and when it failed I started cutting pieces off expecting it would eventually start functioning and I would be able to localize the problem. But that did not happen. I tried clearing it before compiling, but I still cannot deploy. I assume some files must be the cause of the problem, so I tried deleting the Android folder. And a new folder is created, but the problem still continues. Is it possible that the classes.dex file is just created at specific points in the compilation/link and so only are recreated/updated when you do the same operation? Also, that does not explain why it suddenly starts happening for almost all my programs?

I am confused. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up restoring my entire Delphi install from a backup. But I think the problem has something to with one of the following: a) Either the registration database was f.cked up. b) Or it was one of the two folders appdata/local or appdata/roaming that was somehow destroyed. 
I will lay this lie here.